# JsonWebToken encode is undefined

Tags: javascript, authentication, jwt, json-web-token

I'm creating my first ever login system, using JsonWebTokens, and I've hit an obstacle trying to use the `encode` function.

My error message says:

> if (this.ended && !this.hasRejectListeners()) throw reason;
>                                                         ^ TypeError: undefined is not a function

and I've managed to narrow the error down to this line of code:

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

    jwt.encode(payload, superSecret);
```

The function this is a part of looks like this:

```
var moment = require('moment');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var superSecret = require('../config/token.js').secret;

      function (user) {

        var payload = {
          sub: user._id,
          iat: moment().unix(),
          exp: moment().add(14, 'days').unix()
        };

        return = jwt.encode(payload, superSecret);
```

Needless to say, since this is the first time I'm authenticating anything, I don't know why this would cause an error. Please help.

Comment: is `superSecretWord` defined somewhere?

Comment: the function that "looks like this" - that doesn't look like valid javascript AT ALL - can you post more/edit less - the `createJWT: function (user)` hanging there just looks wrong to me

Comment: @JaromandaX The code is now updated, and is valid.